# Formatting Symbology [offset distance] with Arcade Expression in ArcGIS Online

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online, arcade

I'm trying to create a web map that highlights chemistry sampling data for my organization. Each station point has several "chemistry parameters" that needs to be displayed in a "bar chart" format.

The issue I'm running into is that the Arcade expression I used in ArcGIS Pro where I created this map is not being honored once it's shared as a web map.

Is there a process / workflow to include an Arcade expression for modifying symbology?

I just want to understand how to best approach this.

Attached is the data table I'm working with, a screenshot of my webmap, and a screenshot of the ArcGIS Pro symbology that I would like to re-create for the web map. The Arcade expression that worked on ArcGIS Pro was this (using the symbol property connections)...

```
var offsets = {
        "Chlorinated Hydrocarbons": 0,
        "Inorganics": -10,
        "PAH": -20,
        "PCB": -30,
        "PBDE": -40,
        "Pyrethroid": -50,
        // and so on
    }
    return offsets[$feature.parameter]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you publish make sure you uncheck the Use symbols compatible with all clients. This will add the info required to handle the complex symbols with the primitive overrides.
[image: helphelphelp]

One thing you will notice - the labeling in Map Viewer / 4.x JSAPI is a little more aggressive and doesn't follow the symbol override placement. You will have to either increase spacing between symbols or symbol heights and/or do symbols left to right placement. Web map is on Online with the same name but with Russ1 at the end :)

[image: Helpfulimage]